# Smoothly animate a sequence of plots with irregular sampling intervals

Tags: plotting, animation

I have a set of data files that were collected over a period of time at irregular intervals.  I would like to animate plots of these data in such a way that the animation rate is proportional to the real-world process rate.

As a minimum example consider the following set of data with two different sampling rates.  The list animation appears to speed up halfway through because the data sampling rate changes, but the actual wave speed is the same.

```
fakeData = Join[
            Table[Sin[.3 t + 2 x], {t, 0, 10, .5}, {x, 0, 2 π, π/8}],
            Table[Sin[.3 t + 2 x], {t, 12, 40, 2}, {x, 0, 2 π, π/8}]
           ];

ListAnimate[ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}] & /@ fakeData]
```

Where each data set is indexed by the values of t:

```
fakeTimes=Join[
            Table[t, {t, 0, 10, .5}],
            Table[t, {t, 12, 40, 2}]
           ];
```

I can imagine resampling from an interpolation, but I would prefer to have the actual raw data in the animation.  Is there any way to do this directly in Mathematica?  Perhaps a clever use of time series?

Comment: Look up `DisplayDurations` and related options.

Comment: As near as I can tell, DisplayDuration, AnimationRate, etc. apply globally.  Am I misreading the documentation?

Comment: Does your raw data contain the acquisition time stamps though? Your manufactured data does not, and without those, of course you don't have enough information to reconstruct the original time series. Could you post a sample of the actual raw data to see its structure?

Comment: Currently I manage the time stamps in a separate list.  The associated time stamps in the fake data would just be the list of values that t takes inside the Table constructs.